Remind Me function not available in Mail
When I control-select a message in Mail I can't select any of the Remind Me options. The process is described here.
Why can't I select a Remind Me option?


To be able to be reminded about a message in Apple Mail, your email needs to be in an Apple Mail inbox. If you have already filed it into one of your folders then you won't be able to get reminded about the email.
Apple keeps an email to be reminded about in the inbox and after the reminder is set it will put it also in a temporary Remind Me outbox until such time that you're being reminded, at which point the email moves to the top of your inbox.
If your email is already filed away and you don't want to move it back to the inbox, your next best option would probably be to set a reminder in the Reminders app.
